# How to give the Symbolic x,y coordinates and heading inside the frame of the bar chart

Tags: pgfplots

Need to give the x and y coordinates and heading ,inside the frame of the bar chart as like as secound image mentioned there, I had given the code as mentioned below but I got the result as First image

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color} %include colors
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Define bar chart colors
%
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\flushleft
{\color{blue}
\LARGE{Fault summary}\\
}
\flushleft
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
  title    = Names,
               xbar stacked,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        bar width=0.5cm,
        width=10cm,
        height=7cm,
        symbolic y coords={string,module},
        ytick = data
  ]
  \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {(122,string) (63,module)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: the result I got]

[image: I need the result like the secound image, for know I had edited in pdf but I need the bar chart to be generated in latex like this]

Comment: Could any one can please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the pgfplots axes disappear with

```
axis line style={draw=none}
```

and then add the other rectangle e.g. by adding

```
background rectangle/.style={draw},
show background rectangle
```

from the `backgrounds` library to the options of the `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\flushleft
{\color{blue}
\LARGE{Fault summary}\\
}
\flushleft
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={draw},
    show background rectangle]
    \begin{axis}
    [axis line style={draw=none},
    title    = Names,
               xbar stacked,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        bar width=0.5cm,
        width=10cm,
        height=7cm,
        symbolic y coords={string,module},
        ytick = data
  ]
  \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {(122,string) (63,module)};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to solve this problems, got stucked for two days with how to solve this error, now I am got the results perfectly , Thank you again:)